# recurring wait icon

Tags: interrupts

Ubuntu 22.04, x-64, NVIDIA GPU

A circle pie-chart icon keeps popping up
on screen.

The pie sector goes from small to full after a few seconds; any a program that
you're running may then lose focus.

Is this, perhaps, GPU related.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be due to various settings,
in particular the 'animate' setting.

Settings, Accessibility, Enable Animations.

And a related setting that wasn't turning off for awhile :

Settings, Accessibility,click assist, hover click